# I wanna show an element when hovering it using Jquery but even though it recognizes the event it won´t work

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

So, i've seen some other answers for similar stuff, but nothing that really helps or even works, I've tried to follow every step people said in other posts but nothing helped.
I wanna show a sub menu when I hover over it by removing the class hidden that it is defining its display to hiden, but I can´t make it using only css and, even though my js code recognizes that the mouse is hovering through it, it won´t budge.
So, here's my codes

```js
$(".dropdown").hover(function() {
  console.log('hover in');
  $(".dropdown-content").removeClass("hidden");
  console.log('hover out');
  $(".dropdown-content").addClass("hidden");
})
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.menu-desktop {
  position: absolute;
  left: 70%;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.menu-desktop ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.menu-desktop a {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5px;
  color: #bcbcbc;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 0%;
  border-color: transparent;
}

.menu-desktop a:hover {
  color: #858181
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown-content .shown {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 12px 16px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar-itens">
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="assets/9mnb2mazqne71.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <!-- Navigation menu -->
  <ul id="nav" class="menu-desktop">
    <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">EMPRESA</a></li>
    <ul id="submenu" class="dropdown-content hidden">
      <li><a href="#">submenu 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">submenu 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">submenu 1</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">submenu 1</a></li>
      <ul id="submenu2" class="dropdown-content hidden">
        <li><a href="#">submenu 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">submenu 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">submenu 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">submenu 2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </ul>
    <li><a href="#">CLIENTES</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CONTATO</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

EDIT: Forgot to include my css, so, here it is!

Comment: You immediately add the class back after removing it, so why would you expect your element to become visible?

Comment: Please provide feedback on my extensive answer.

Answer (score 0):

## The problems with your code

### Main problem

You **immediately** add the class back after removing it, so you **never** see the dropdown content.

jQuery's `.hover()` expects **two** function arguments (first is run when mouse enters, second when mouse leaves).

### direct-child-only problem

Second problem with your code is that it toggles the class on ***all*** submenus while the one you want is **only the direct, immediate child of the list item being hovered**. You can use

```
$(this).find(".dropdown-content").first()
```

to only affect the sub-`ul` you want. Alternatively, instead of `.first()`, you can also use `.eq(0)`.

### Invalid html problem

Please also note that `ul` can only have `li` children, so you need to wrap any sub-`ul` inside an `li`.

#### The solution to *not*  use

```js
$(".dropdown").hover(
  function() {
     $(this).find(".dropdown-content").first().removeClass("hidden");
  }, 
  function() {
     $(this).find(".dropdown-content").eq(0).addClass("hidden");
  }
);
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="nav" class="menu-desktop">
  <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">EMPRESA</a>
    <ul id="submenu" class="dropdown-content hidden">
      <li><a href="#">submenu 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">submenu 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">submenu 1</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">submenu 1</a>
        <ul id="submenu2" class="dropdown-content hidden">
          <li><a href="#">submenu 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">submenu 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">submenu 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">submenu 2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">CLIENTES</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">CONTATO</a></li>
</ul>
```

### The solution to use is *CSS only*

That being said, you don't need any JavaScript for this, and you shouldn't be using JS for a CSS job:

```css
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown:hover > .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="nav" class="menu-desktop">
  <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">EMPRESA</a>
    <ul id="submenu" class="dropdown-content">
      <li><a href="#">submenu 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">submenu 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">submenu 1</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">submenu 1</a>
        <ul id="submenu2" class="dropdown-content">
          <li><a href="#">submenu 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">submenu 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">submenu 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">submenu 2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">CLIENTES</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">CONTATO</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare function inside hover() to handle hover in & out event:

```
$( ".dropdown" ).hover(
  function() {
     $(".dropdown-content").removeClass("hidden");
  }, function() {
     $(".dropdown-content").addClass("hidden");
  }
);
```

Comment: The problem is that even after I did what you showed me it won´t work. Have maybe...some better idea to how do this instead of trying this way im doing? Also, thanks for trying to help me!

Comment: @TheHolyHelena on a side note, you already had `.hidden` class that does `display: none`. You don't need it in `.dropdown-content`